# How to realize modifying call in REST API

Tags: web-services, rest, http

Assume you have some resource behind a REST API. This resource could well be modified using the usual HTTP verbs PUT or PATCH. But let's assume the server behind the API has to check some prerequisites to decide if the modification on the resource can be made or not (e.g. withdraw an amount from a bank account).

In this case there is no use in using POST (because we do not want to add a new resource), nor PUT or PATCH, because only the server knows about the new value of the resources' modified attribute, if he will allow the requested modification at all. In the above example the account's new balance would have to be computed on the server side like so : balance = balance - amount, and to my knowledge all the client can do with PUT or PATCH is to send the *already modified* resource (the account) or atttribute of that resource (the accounts' balance).

Am I then right in assuming that in this case the API designer has to provide a parameter (e.g. .../account?withdraw=amount) with the URL pointing to the resource ? What would be the correct HTTP verb for this operation ?

Comment: Your question is a bit fuzzy... but I assume you are looking for a simple "HTTP POST". The syntax of the URL is irrelevant and in a POST request it typically does _not_ carry any query part. The payload is "posted".

Comment: see my edits to be less fuzzy

Comment: That doesn't change anything. You are trying to send a change request, so incomplete data. That is what a POST is for.

Comment: Right, it should be a POST, but not directly to the resource to be updated, but to another one that knows about how to update the original resource -> see accepted answer.

Comment: POST doesn't *have* to create a new resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no use in using POST (because we do not want to add a new resource)

You do. A monetary exchange can be expressed in a transaction, hence: you're creating a new transaction.

So simply perform a POST with the transaction details to a `/transaction` endpoint.

You certainly don't want to allow users to `PUT` their new account balance, as that would require atomicity over HTTP, which is all REST stands against: the client would have to know the pre-transaction balance, and make sure in some way no transaction will be carried out before theirs arrives.